# Why am i able to authenticate with the password hash in Java Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot-starter

I am using `spring-boot-starter-security`. I configured my `WebSecurityConfigation` to use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` provider and `BCryptPasswordEncoder` for authentication. Also the `UserDetailsService` implementation returns a `User` object with the `password` field set to the actual hash.

It seems to work fine. However i noticed that i could successfully authenticate with either the password *or* the hash.

For example the password itself is a generated UUID `51a80a6a-8618-4583-98d2-d77d103a62c6` which was encoded to `$2a$10$u4OSZf7B9yJvQ5UYNNpy7O4f3g0gfUMl2Xmm3h282W.3emSN3WqxO`.

Full web security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DemoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("SUPER", "BASIC");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("BASIC").and().httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}

@Service
public class DemoUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDAO userDAO = userRepository.findByEmailAndActivated(email);
        if (userDAO == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Email %s not found", email));
        }
        return new User(email, userDAO.getPasswordHash(), getGrantedAuthorities(email));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(String email) {
        return asList(() -> "ROLE_BASIC");
    }
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

Why am i able to authenticate with both strings? Am i doing something wrong, or is this expected or some configuration? I was unable to find anything in docs.

Comment: What are the odds but ... check by encoding the encoded String, this could be the same output (I really doubt that). Since a result hash is not unique, this is possible, unlikely but possible

Comment: show the configuration, cause i have also implemented security on bcrypt and i do not notice any kind of this.

Comment: @shutdown -h now what configuration do you exactly mean?

Comment: I'd say dig deep with the debugger. Verify that the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Debugging shows me that if i use the password, it is correctly hashed and checked. This is fine.
However - when i use the hash, i see that the PlaintextPasswordEncoder is used to check the password. This is why i'm able to use the hash. I still don't see how the PlaintextPasswordEncoder ends up in my code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this thing happens because according to your config you're actually get two `DaoAuthenticationProvider`s. One is explicit, configured by you, and one is implicit, that gets configured under the hood, when you're calling `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);`, and for this implicit provider you're not setting password encoder.

Try this out:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()); 
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("SUPER", "BASIC");
}
```

And remove your manually configured provider - seems that you're actually dont need it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually you're right. Adding (userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()); helped.

Answer (score -2):

Best approach would be to hook up the debugger. The actual logic of using PasswordEncoder for matching password is in `additionalAuthenticationChecks` method of `DaoAuthenticationProvider`

```
 protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object salt = null;

        if (this.saltSource != null) {
            salt = this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);
        }

        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(), presentedPassword, salt)) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
        }
    }
```

This delegates to `BCryptPasswordEncoder`

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        if (encodedPassword == null || encodedPassword.length() == 0) {
            logger.warn("Empty encoded password");
            return false;
        }
    if (!BCRYPT_PATTERN.matcher(encodedPassword).matches()) {
        logger.warn("Encoded password does not look like BCrypt");
        return false;
    }

    return BCrypt.checkpw(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not an answer.